# How can I display all anchor categories even with no result (empty category)?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, layered-navigation

[image]

How can I display all anchor categories in Magento (1.9.0.1) even with no result (empty category) as for attribute product?

As default behavior when I set "anchor" a category, this is shown in "Shopping by" section only if is no empty. I'ld like to show all categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say this filtering happens here:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Category.php:170
if ($category->getIsActive() && $category->getProductCount()) {
```

So, rewrite this class and remove `$category->getProductCount()`.

But I didn't test it.

Comment: Thank you for reply. It works like a charm but I can do it without edit core file directly? Is there a way? Further, empty categories are shown now as text, how can I show they as links?

Comment: Check the tempalte for the links. And you want to rewrite the model, not edit the core file: http://magedev.com/magento-overriding-model-block-or-helper/